# Block display canvas still a gap at the bottom

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have searched here on the property `display: block` should have fixed the gap between the canvas and the div but for some reason the gap still persists.

```js
function SetHeight(canvas)
{
  var div       = $(".outer");
  canvas.width  = div.innerWidth();
  canvas.height = div.innerHeight();
  console.log(div.innerHeight(), div.height(), canvas.height);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var canvas    = $("#canvas")[0];
  SetHeight(canvas);
  $(window).on("resize", function(){
     SetHeight(canvas);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*width: 100%; font-size:100%*/
}

canvas {
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
}

.outer {
  padding: 0;
  top: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer col-xs-12">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="col-xs-12"></canvas>
</div>
```

from what i can see on the console there is a `0.2` diffrence between `div.innerHeight()` and `canvas.height`.

`div.innerHeight()` is equal to `div.height()`.

What I have tried:

1. Setting the `line-height :0` to `.outer` and `canvas
2. Setting `vertical-align: bottom` to `canavs`

This is coded on `codepen.io` if that at all makes a diffrence

Comment: This is because <canvas> has default `width` and `height` properties set to 300 and 150 respectively. If you are going to use this canvas, you will probably have to change these values anyway.

Comment: along with that you need to change the `height` of `outer` class

Comment: Yea sorry that was done in js, one second posting

Comment: @qwn there is no need of using **jquery** for the `height `issue you can do that using **CSS**, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS SOLUTION FOR THE CANVAS HEIGHT FIX**

In my opinion, the gap comes because the height of the `.outer` and `<canvas>` does not match, I have solved this using:

```
canvas {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and also providing `position: relative;` to the `.outer`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*width: 100%; font-size:100%*/
}

canvas {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  padding: 0;
  top: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer col-xs-12">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

***Now FIX for your snippet***

Your `jQuery` is working fine the issue was with `bootstrap CSS` the class `.col-xs-12` puts `padding` to the `<div>` and `<canvas>` making the gap.

To fix this I just used `padding:0 !important;` to the `.outer` div and `<canvas>` check the fiddle below:

```js
function SetHeight(canvas)
{
  var div       = $(".outer");
  canvas.width  = div.innerWidth();
  canvas.height = div.innerHeight();
  console.log(div.innerHeight(), div.height(), canvas.height);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var canvas    = $("#canvas")[0];
  SetHeight(canvas);
  $(window).on("resize", function(){
     SetHeight(canvas);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*width: 100%; font-size:100%*/
}

canvas {
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
  padding:0 !important;
  
}

.outer {
  padding:0 !important;
  top: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer col-xs-12">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="col-xs-12"></canvas>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: I dont use `height: 100%` since it seems to blur the canvas, rather I set the `canvas.height` through js, I have edited the question.

Comment: did you tried my code with your original code.? because as far as I know, this will work the same.

Comment: Yea it works with `height: 100%`. but as I understand it should work my way as well yes?

Comment: @qwn yeah It should, but a CSS solution is much better than jQuery solution[*CSS will have less error and less load*], i will check for the bug in your solution.

Comment: @qwn I have updated my answer with Fix for your fiddle. Please do check it and if there is any doubt please do ask.

Answer (score 1):

[weBer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001816/9143578) is technically the better way to do it, given the option - dimensions calculated using CSS in the browser are faster and more accurate than JavaScript. However, I will continue with the JavaScript method since you have asked for that.

Since you're using jQuery to "measure" rendered heights, the result will often not be an integer. Fractional pixel values are not rendered too precisely in most browsers, they often just round up or down.

If you want to stay with JS instead of CSS, rounding your div height to the nearest pixel before you modify the canvas size:

`div.height(Math.round(div.height()));`

(I should reiterate that this is far from an ideal technique - I'm giving it as an answer to solve your specific problem and to explain why it is happening).

Doing this will also leave a second problem - the `box-sizing` mode is content-box, which means that the div border adds 1px to the height (leaving a gap). To work around this, set the div to:

`box-sizing: border-box;`

**Full snippet:**

```js
function SetHeight(canvas)
{
  var div       = $(".outer");
  
  // Round the div height to the nearest pixel
  div.height(Math.round(div.height()));
  
  canvas.width  = div.innerWidth();
  canvas.height = div.innerHeight();
  console.log(div.innerHeight(), div.height(), canvas.height);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var canvas    = $("#canvas")[0];
  SetHeight(canvas);
  $(window).on("resize", function(){
     SetHeight(canvas);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*width: 100%; font-size:100%*/
}

canvas {
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
}

.outer {
  /* ADD BORDER-BOX TO REMOVE GAP */
  box-sizing: border-box;

  padding: 0;
  top: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer col-xs-12">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="col-xs-12"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand now